# How can i use embedded Jetty with JSFUnit?

Tags: java, embedded, junit, jetty, jsfunit

I would like to test my JSF application using JSFUnit and embedded Jetty. How can i do this? Is there any documentation which demonstrates this?

I started a jetty server programatically using junit4's @BeforeClass but it seems JSFUnit tries to connect to the server before the static method annotated with @BeforeClass can execute!

Answer (score 0):

I am using mortbay plugin to start jetty as a part of maven build. Hope this helps.